# LEFT JOIN to make different Select if empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a LEFT JOIN between two tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM ".T_STAFF_ROLE." AS sr
LEFT JOIN ".T_STAFF_SCHEDULE." AS ss 
ON sr.id = ss.staff_role_id
WHERE ss.client_booking_id=".$id_booking;
```

The `T_STAFF_ROLE` as 10 entries, all with different roles/function. This number is fixed.

I would like that if the Select returns empty because there is no one assigned to the specific `$id_booking` to return anyway the list of roles/functions from `sr` even if with a empty/null value.

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `WHERE` would filter non-null values. Place condition into `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ".T_STAFF_ROLE." AS sr
LEFT JOIN ".T_STAFF_SCHEDULE." AS ss 
ON sr.id = ss.staff_role_id 
AND ss.client_booking_id=".$id_booking;
```

-this will force to add matched rows even if it's `NULL` because of `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT *
FROM ".T_STAFF_ROLE." AS sr
LEFT JOIN ".T_STAFF_SCHEDULE." AS ss 
ON ( sr.id = ss.staff_role_id AND ss.client_booking_id=" . $id_booking . ")
```